# How can I find a list of methods of Array type in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm looking for a list of methods that I can use on Array in Swift.
For example you can run `isEmpty` on an array, but I couldn't find a list of all methods.

For exmaple I couldn't find global functions like `find` in the formal [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_135)

Comment: @nicael the Language Guide is not a complete API reference

Comment: There is a Swift Standard Library documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/), but it is extremely incomplete

Comment: @user102008 thank you so much. I have been looking all over for this.

Answer (score 4):

When you <kbd>cmd</kbd>-click a built-in function or type Xcode displays a generated file with the entire contents of the module to which that function or type belongs. In this case, if you <kbd>cmd</kbd>-click a Swift type (like `String`) or function (like `find`), you can see the declarations for the entire Swift built-in library.